# DataGridCell style of Center is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-style

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100">
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100">
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group" Binding="{Binding Group, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100">
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I am trying to apply Center text allignment to the GridCell but it does not work and looks weird.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `TextAlignment` property to `Center`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: No such property `HorizontalContentAlignment` exist and gives compilation error.

Comment: try this: TextAlignment